# Access to local Ms Access (.mdb) from google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

Well, I am totally newby here and this is my first question, so I beg pardon if I don't fullfil some rule...

I would like to access to data stored locally on a .mdb file (Ms Access 2003) to use those data in Google Apps Scripts.

I have been searching  about it and it seems that it could be done through JDBC service if the database would  be served by MySQL, but I need to do it without server, just locally.

Yes, my english is poor; I hope I have managed to explain clearly enought.

Thank you very much, indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Ms Access is not a database server, but a file-based Office application, there's no easy way to access Access the way you want. All applications doing that use Microsoft C#/.NET libraries to do so.

Comment: Thanks, Michael. I was longing for another answer, but it is not your fault :-)   Maybe I can try to set up an light MySQL service just for the time I have to get data from the database. PD: I cant mark your answer, due to lack of reputation...